# What anime is this video featuring girls wearing Nazi armband from? (NSFW)

Tags: identification-request

My friend sends me this video of an anime featuring what seems to be Nazi (?)

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sJsRswmAiWo

Neither of us knows what anime it was from. Does anyone know?

Below is a SFW screenshot, as requested:

[image]

Comment: Please also upload a SFW screenshot as a safeguard.

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I did a reverse image search on one of the frames in the video. It's an hentai anime from 1986 called [**Cream Lemon**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_Lemon). I haven't watched it and I am not going to, but if you want to know more about check [its Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cream_Lemon).

[This](http://animeraw.com/archives/5090) is what the reverse image search turned up.

Comment: Episode 14, Nalice Scramble, to be exact.